# Given two equations $(xax)^3 = bx$ and $x^2a = (xa)^{-1}$ in a nonabelian group, solve for $x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is for a basic non-commutative group.

My steps:

$(xax)^3 = bx$

$xaxxaxxax = bx$

$xax^2ax^2ax = bx$

$xax^2ax^2a = b$

$x^2a = (xax^2a)^{-1}b$

Now, substituting $x^2a$ into the second equation:

$(xax^2a)^{-1}b = (xa)^{-1}$

$b = (xax^2a)(xa)^{-1} $

$b = (xax^2a)(a^{-1}x^{-1})$

$b = xax$

Now back to the first equation:

$b^3 = bx$

$b^2 = x$

Apparently, this is not the correct answer according to my answer sheet.

Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Your solution seems okay to me.

Comment: Also, again, please [edit] the title.

Comment: Answer sheet says $(ab)^{-1} = x$

Comment: I think the answer sheet might be wrong. I've checked your solution several times; as I said, it seems okay to me.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: From $b=xax$ and $x=b^2$, we see that $a=b^{-3}$, so both expressions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $xaxxaxxax=bx$, so
$$
xa(x^2a)(x^2a)=b
$$
Now $a(x^2a)=a(xa)^{-1}=aa^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}$ and therefore
$$
b=xx^{-1}a^{-1}x^{-1}=a^{-1}x^{-1}
$$
whence $x^{-1}=ab$ and $x=(ab)^{-1}$.

Can we say that $b^2=(ab)^{-1}$? This is equivalent to $b^3=a^{-1}$ or, as you proved that $b^3=bx$, to $bx=a^{-1}$, which is true.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the answer sheet is equivalent; your solution is fine.

Marking your work line by line . . .

> My steps:
>
> $(xax)^3 = bx$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark\text{Def}}$
>
> $xaxxaxxax = bx$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark\text{Def}}$
>
> $xax^2ax^2ax = bx$$\color{red}{\quad\checkmark\text{Rewrite}}$
>
> $xax^2ax^2a = b$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark (\times x^{-1})}$
>
> $x^2a = (xax^2a)^{-1}b$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark (\times (xax^2a)^{-1})}$
>
> Now, substituting $x^2a$ into the second equation:
>
> $(xax^2a)^{-1}b = (xa)^{-1}$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark (\text{Sub})}$
>
> $b = (xax^2a)(xa)^{-1} $ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark (\times (xax^2a))}$
>
> $b = (xax^2a)(a^{-1}x^{-1})$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark (\text{Use of 'inverse of product' lemma})}$
>
> $b = xax$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark (\text{Use of inverses})}$
>
> Now back to the first equation:
>
> $b^3 = bx$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark (\text{Sub})}$
>
> $b^2 = x$ $\color{red}{\quad\checkmark (\times b^{-1})}$

Comment: Is it possible that both answers are correct? That $(ab)^{-1} = b^2$?

Comment: Yes, @DavidDavidson. I don't see how though. I've edited the question accordingly. I am going to improve this answer further in a short while.

Comment: @DavidDavidson Is that clear now?

Comment: The steps from the answer sheet seem to be:

$(xax)^3 = bx$ | 
$xax^2ax^2ax = bx$ | 
$xa(xa)^{-1}(xa)^{-1}x = bx$ | 
$xaa^{-1}x^{-1}a^{-1}x^{-1}x = bx$ | 
$a^{-1}x^{-1}=b$ | 
$b^{-1}a^{-1} = x$ | 
$(ab)^{-1} = x$ |

Comment: Then your answer sheet is correct *too*. You're both right, @DavidDavidson.

Answer (score -2):

1. The following is  solution in the image attached from the link.
   [solution Image on paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6nr3.jpg)

Form the above solution x = b-1a-1. substituting this in second equation given. a = b-3. which the solution b^2 can be written in infinite ways if you include a like b3ab2, b6a2b2 etc etc.

Comment: (xa)−1 is not equal to (a−1x−1). a need not be invertible.

Comment: No, the solution is correct.

Comment: Here $a$ is an element of the group. It is invertible *by definition*.

Comment: Yeah, right. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: It is well known that for any $g, h$ in any group $G$, we have $(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$.

Comment: Please delete your answer.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: That's better, but please [edit] the question again using MathJax.